# Data Replicator connection string for use with Data Hub

Tags: exact-online, invantive-data-hub

I am trying to set up Invantive Data Hub with Replicator. The default discovery creates entries for Exact Online and others, but there is no entry in settings.xml which shows me how to configure data cache.

This one exists for example:

```
<connection name="Exact Online (nl)" id="c149becf-01d3-4a58-9ee7-7369f34bdff5" description="{res:itgen_demo_exact_online_combined_nl}" sortingOrder="1000" authentication="Application" userLogonCodeMode="Auto" passwordMode="Auto" createdBy="jbu" createdOn="WS102" creationDate="2017-08-17T13:53:23.9351965+02:00">
  <database order="0" createdBy="jbu" createdOn="WS102" creationDate="2017-08-17T13:53:23.9071956+02:00" provider="ExactOnlineAll" connectionString="apiUrl=https://start.exactonline.nl" />
</connection>
```

The console app has no editor for the settings.xml, so it must be done manually.

How can I configure the Replicator connection string to be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Google with different keywords, I've found a working setup. First Add a file `settings-something.xml` in the %USERPROFILE%\invantive.

The give it contents like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<settings xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="3" forcedefault="false">
  <group name="Jurriaan" >
    <connection name="Exact Online with PostgreSQL Data Cache" dataCacheConnectionString="provider=PostgreSql;connectionString={Server=dbserver;Database=db;User Id=db_owner;Password=db_pwd}" >
      <database provider="ExactOnlineAll" connectionString="apiUrl=https://start.exactonline.nl" />
    </connection>
  </group>
</settings>
```

It would be handy when there would be a connection editor on Data Hub or at least a sample :-)